# How to deal number and string in ui:repeat and wind rose highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, uirepeat

I have following code for generating dynamic windrose in highchart:

the second and third `<td>` only accepts numbers and my var=val is an array of numbers. But I need to show "N", "S", "E", "W" in  first `<td>`. How can I generate an array so that my ui:repeat display "N", "S", "E", "W" in first `<td>` and their corresponding values in second and third `<td>`. My second and third `<td>` showing correct value using ui:repeat. I just need to show to string in first `<td>`.

Any suggestions please.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.wind_rose_data_table}" var="val" varStatus="status">       
<tr>
<td class="dir">"N"</td>
<td class="data">#{val[0]}</td>
<td class="data">#{val[1]}</td>     
</tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Comment: code is here:
<ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.wind_rose_data_table}" var="val" varStatus="status">   
<tr>
<td class="dir">"N"</td>
<td class="data">#{val[0]}</td>
<td class="data">#{val[1]}</td>  
</tr>
</ui:repeat>

Comment: It is difficult to read code in comments. Please edit your question and put the code there. If you indent it by four spaces it will render correctly, and even have syntax highlighting.

Comment: I dont know how to indent code there. Could you please tell me.

Comment: You can indent manually, or select your code and click the `{}` button, or select your code and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: Could you reproduce your exampel as live demo, instead of piece of code